# How to check for delivery report when using "*0#" method?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, telephony

Before I explain further, I would like to say this is for an [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/) module, but I don't believe the information I need relies on any Xposed knowledge.

I'm writing a method just know which (thanks to Xposed) runs just before `onReceive` method is called of a class `SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`. For those not familiar with Xposed, this just allows me to place a method before `onReceive` any time it is called, allowing me to check arguments sent to it, change arguments, among other things.

But this is just for background, my real need is to figure out how to check if a message received is a delivery report.

My network (giffgaff) allows delivery reports by prepending `*0#` to messages, which when received on the other phones, replies automatically with a delivery report. So for example, this would occur.

Sender sends: `*0#Test`

Receiver sees: `Test`

Sender sees: `Message [number here] to [number here] delivered at [time] on [date] Text: 'Test'`

I've tried using `getResultCode()` to check if the received text is a delivery report but this does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from available information on GiffGaff, your delivery report comes through as a regular SMS message, in which case there's nothing to distinguish it from any other message, apart from the content. I doubt the originating address would even be of any help, as it would most likely be a service center number, not the destination address.

So, about the only way to figure that out would be to parse the message and see if it fits the template you've shown, and if the destination numbers agree.

Comment: I was thinking as much, thanks for confirming. So strictly speaking, this is different from a standard delivery report?

Comment: If by standard delivery report, you mean the functionality offered through the SmsManager API, then yes, this is a little different. Even with the API, delivery report status and conditions vary widely between providers. In your case, GiffGaff just handles it by sending you a regular old text message as confirmation.

Comment: Very interesting. Accepted your answer, and thanks for your help.